# Caliburn Micro and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, caliburn.micro

I am having problems following the Caliburn Micro documentation examples and other examples for that matter using Visual Studio 2013.

In the documentation http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/, I have been trying to follow the Silverlight example. I have created a Silverlight project in VS 2013 and used nuget for the latest Caliburn Micro toolkit (V2.02).

First problem: `BootstrapperBase` class not recognized in my project. Instead I used `Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel>` as a workaround.

Second Problem the code snippet below does not work:

```
<Button Content="Click Me">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SayHello" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I get the follow error in the xaml: "A value of type 'ActionMessage' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionColection' ".

Is the problem with Visual Studio 2013 (I think the examples used Visual Studio 2010), or is the documentation out of date?

Marinos.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of Caliburn.Micro 2.0 bootstrapper code has changed, and the documentation is for 1.5 series.

This should work

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Click]=[SayHello()]" Content="Click Me" />
```

as is this

```
<Button x:Name="SayHello" Content="Click Me" />
```

Updated (use `Message.Attach`). See [Actions docs](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

Comment: The first method still doesn't work. error given:
The property "Attach" does not exist in the "http://www.caliburnproject.org"